# Which spider is this? Is it dangerous?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

So today while clearing the trash out of my room I found this orange spider on an abandoned piece of foam.[image: Spider1]
[image: Spider4]
 It is carrying a weird ball with it wherever it goes. What is this? And to which genus does this spider belongs?

For a better contrast I placed it on  paper.
[image: Spider2]
[image: Spider3]

**EDIT-1**

**Size**: Roughly 1cm in length

**Location**: Uttar Pradesh, India. Coordinates- https://maps.app.goo.gl/svXoxaH4Z2lK2rFH2

**Temperature**: 34°C and Humid.

**EDIT-2**

Adding few more pics

[image: Spider5]
[image: Spider6]
[image: Spider7]
[image: Spider8]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clearly a Theridiid (cobweb) spider, but it doesn't look like the Parasteatoda tepidariorum I'm familiar with here in the US.  The egg sac it's holding indicates it's a mature female, and the regular pattern on the abdomen is both distinctive and unlike the variable, blotchy pattern of tepidariorum.  Unfortunately, not being familiar with Eurasian spiders likely to be found in your area, I can't be of much help as to what it might be, beyond limiting it to the Theridiids.
Oh, yes - it's pretty clearly not one of the Widows (Latrodectus spp.), and since those are the only medically significant Theridiids we know, it's not dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasteatoda_tepidariorum

I have personally come across these little spiders at my place and they look very similar to the Parasteatoda tepidariorum.

Comment: Can you add an image, check whether its distribution includes India, add a little background why you think it is this species  *etc*? We discourage one-liners

Comment: @AliceD I am sorry as this was meant to be a comment but was not able to do so because of the reputation policies that encourage to write answers when you are new.